# Ajuda, gerar gráficos com json

Tags: javascript

Preciso gerar um gráfico do tipo Pie Cart utilizando js e json, tenho o arquivo json com o nome dos cursos e quantidade de aprovados por curso, preciso que o js leia essas informações e gere o gráfico com elas
"Não consigo gerar o gráfico exemplo: ler o json e tratar os dados para que ele mostre no gráfico automaticamente. Quero que os nomes dos Cursos e os números de aprovados que estão no json, preencham os campos necessários e gere os gráficos."

```
var nome_course;
var aprovados;

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("./report/report_curso.json", function (json) {

let nome_curso = json["nome_curso"];
let aprovados = json["matriculados"];

});
});


Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito', '-apple-system,system- 
ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#858796';

// Pie Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
labels: [nome_curso],
datasets: [{
  data: [aprovados],
  backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
  hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
  hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
  }],
  },
  options: {
   maintainAspectRatio: false,
   tooltips: {
  backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
  bodyFontColor: "#858796",
  borderColor: '#dddfeb',
  borderWidth: 1,
  xPadding: 15,
  yPadding: 15,
  displayColors: false,
  caretPadding: 10,
  },
   legend: {

  display: false
   },
   cutoutPercentage: 80,
   },
   });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Json: 
[{"nome_curso":"Curso 1","matriculados":"673"},{"nome_curso":"Curso2","matriculados":"906"},{"nome_curso":"Curso3","matriculados":"489"}]

Comment: Qual seria o problema ?

Comment: Não consigo gerar o gráfico exemplo: ler o json e tratar os dados para que ele mostre no gráfico automaticamente. Quero que os nomes dos Cursos e os números de aprovados que estão no json, preencham os campos necessários e gere os gráficos.

Comment: Queres usar o resultado da consulta `getJSON` no gráfico é isso ?

Comment: Para ler um json é preciso utilizar métodos do Javascript para tanto como **map()** ou **forEach()** por exemplo, se vc ainda sabe mexer com tais ferramentas acredito que ainda não esteja preparado par mexer com gráficos.

Comment: sim isso mesmo no caso do gráfico ali onde está "Labels:" seria inserido o nome dos cursos no formato EX: ["nome do curso 1","nome do curso 2"]. E onde está "data:" o número dos matriculados no formato EX:["673","906"]

Comment: sei trabalhar também com forEach(), porém bem pouco, por isso vim pedir ajuda, alguma luz para que consiga fazer oque necessito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Antes de tudo é necessário relembrar de algumas coisas.

- Temos que relembrar que o JS é **síncrono**, ou seja, ele não espera a sua consulta *ajax* para após gerar o gráfico, ele vai fazer isso tudo de um vez, pode ser que em alguns casos que a consulta seja instantânea, consiga atribuir o valor à variável, mas isso é um risco enorme.
- Para facilitar use um retorno json baseado nessa lógica

  ```
  { 
      "matriculados": ["673", "906", "489"], 
      "nome_curso": ["Curso 1", "Curso 2", "Curso 3"] 
  }
  ```

### Qual seria a solução para o problema?

#### Solução 1

- Criar o gráfico dentro da sua consulta *ajax*, assim após a consulta será possível usar os valores do gráfico sem nenhum problema, ficando algo parecido com isso:

  ```
  $.getJSON("./report/report_curso.json", function (json) {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
      var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'doughnut',
          data: {
              labels: json.nome_curso,
              datasets: [{
                  data: json.matriculados,
                  backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
                  hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
                  hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
              }],
          }
      });
  });
  ```

#### Solução 2

- Tornar sua função assíncrona, ou seja, fazer com que obrigatoriamente, antes de criar o gráfico seja necessário aguardar o retorno da consulta *ajax* , ficando algo parecido com isso:

  ```
  const createGraph = async () => {
      let nome_curso = [];
      let matriculados = [];

      $.getJSON("./report/report_curso.json", function (json) {

          nome_curso = json.nome_curso;
          matriculados = json.matriculados;

      });

      var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
      var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'doughnut',
          data: {
              labels: [nome_curso],
              datasets: [{
                  data: [matriculados],
                  backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
                  hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
                  hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
              }],
          }
      });
  }
  ```

#### Solução 3

- Caso queria continuar usando o formato `json` como no anunciado, pode realizar a lógico da consulta `ajax` dessa forma:

  ```
  $.getJSON("./report/report_curso.json", function (json) {

      let cursos_json = [];
      let matriculados_json = [];

      for (let index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
          cursos_json.push(json[index].nome_curso); // add nome do curso no array
          matriculados_json.push(json[index].matriculados);  // add matricula no array
      }

  })
  ```

---

#### Referências:

[ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/)

[Funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)

Comment: Entendi tudo certinho o problema é que o meu json é automaticamente gerado de outro lugar, então ele vem no formato que passei :(

Comment: Editei a resposta, basta usar essa lógica na consulta `ajax` e atribuição das variáveis.

Comment: deu certinho, muito obrigado!